# I want a way to add post with specific category without enter to posts and choose category

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a website with theme clients  doesn't wants to open all posts and add post and choose category  (he wants open dashboard and see (category1 )( category2 )( category3 ) when he press on one he directly add post to the selected  category
i was trying to  use UPT UI but it's not working

Comment: Can you please try explaining your question more clearly? Are you trying to create a dashboard widget that lists categories?

Comment: it's done i used custom post type  , and i create button on the dashboard with link to create new post in spasfic catogry